# How to append new rows to CSV file with Pandas

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, append

Hi, I am trying to append four variables (score, gender, class and initials) into a CSV file so it displays as so:

```
with open ('untitled.csv','w') as file_out:
    file_out.write(score)
    file_out.write(real_player_class)
    file_out.write(current_player_gender)
    file_out.write(current_player_initials)

df_test = pd.read_csv('untitled.csv')
df_test
```

I would like the result to look like this in a Dataframe:

```
score gender class initials
```

with the stats underneath them, like this:

```
score gender class initials
1        M  senior   YTU
```

Currently, in my code, this is what the dataframe looks like (in a dataframe):
    0seniorMYTU

Is there a way to solve this? How do I append the score, gender, class and initials variables into their respective columns?

Thanks!

Comment: You should invest some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer and you may even start to get ideas for solving your problem.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

You need commas between values and newlines between rows. You can write them manually or use the  csv module for convince.